# loop over dict key-value-pair or each element in dict

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary

I have a dict that looks something like :
`PathNameRxn = {'ID':'2048 444','Name':'john hh', 'Father Name':'David ll'}`

and this function:

```
def DefGrp(PathNameRxn): #.split("_")[0]
    groups=""
#   RxnID = Rxn.ID
    #print(PathName)
    for PathName in PathNameRxn:
        group= '''      <groups:group sboTerm="SBO:0000633" groups:id="group" groups:name="'''+PathName+'''" groups:kind="partonomy">
        <groups:listOfMembers>\n'''      
        for RxnID in PathNameRxn[PathName].split():
            idRef = '''          <groups:member groups:idRef="'''+str(RxnID.split("_")[0])+'''"/>\n'''
            groups += idRef            
        listOfMembers= '''        </groups:listOfMembers>
      </groups:group>''' 
        return group+groups+listOfMembers
```

this code

```
listOfGroups=DefGrp(PathNameRxn)
print(listOfGroups)
```

gives me:

```
<groups:group sboTerm="SBO:0000633" groups:id="group" groups:name="ID" groups:kind="partonomy">
        <groups:listOfMembers>
          <groups:member groups:idRef="2048"/>
          <groups:member groups:idRef="444"/>
        </groups:listOfMembers>
      </groups:group>
```

but I want:

```
<groups:group sboTerm="SBO:0000633" groups:id="group" groups:name="ID" groups:kind="partonomy">
        <groups:listOfMembers>
          <groups:member groups:idRef="2048"/>
          <groups:member groups:idRef="444"/>
        </groups:listOfMembers>
      </groups:group>
<groups:group sboTerm="SBO:0000633" groups:id="group" groups:name="Name" groups:kind="partonomy">
        <groups:listOfMembers>
          <groups:member groups:idRef="john"/>
          <groups:member groups:idRef="hh"/>
        </groups:listOfMembers>
      </groups:group>
```

can someone help me to achieve this? I want to loop though every element of my dict

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your return statement is indented wrong.